# T-SQL Select first instance

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that contains patient locations.  I'm trying to find the first patient location that is not the emergency department.  I tried using `MIN` but since the locations have numbers in them it pulls the `MIN` location but not necessarily the first location.  There is a datetime field associated with the location, but I'm not certain how to link the `min` `datetime` to the first location.  Any help would be appreciated.  My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT PatientName,
       MRN,
       CSN,
       MIN (LOC) as FirstUnit,
       MIN (DateTime)as FirstUnitTime
FROM Patients
WHERE LOC <> 'ED'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that you want the first unit for each patient.  If so, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select PatientName, MRN, CSN, LOC as FirstUnit, DateTime as FirstUnitTime
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by PatientName, MRN, CSN
                                order by datetime asc) as seqnum
      from Patients p
      where loc <> 'ED'
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` assigns a sequential number to a group of rows, where the group is specified by the `partition by` clause.  The numbers are in order, as defined by the `order by` clause.  So, the oldest (first) row in each group is assigned a value of 1.  The outside query chooses this row.

Comment: I have worked with row_number() and partition by before successfully. However I often struggle with it. Yours is the most clear and succinct explanation I have seen. Thank you for it. It definitely helps me track the logical flow in my mind.